# Proof of Inverse DFT

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-transform, orthogonality

In "The Discrete Fourier Transform" of Ivan W. Selesnick, proof of inverse DFT written as

\begin{align}
 {x_0(j)} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{y(k)}\omega _n^{ - kj}} \nonumber \\
 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{n - 1} {{x_0(l)}\omega _n^{kl}} } \right)\omega _n^{ - kj}} \nonumber \\
 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{n - 1} {{x_0(l)}} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\omega _n^{k(j - l)}}  \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{n - 1} {{x_0(l)}} \;n\;\delta(\langle j - l\rangle_n)  \\
 &= {x_0(j)}
\end{align}

with
\begin{equation*}
 \delta(m)  = 
 \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if }m=0, \\
  0, & \text{if }m \ne 0,
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\omega_n=e^\frac{2\pi{}i}{n}
\end{equation*}
and $\langle r \rangle_n$ is $r$ modulo $n$.

My question in the last two line of the proof. How the detail computation for $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{n - 1} {{x_0(l)}} \;n\; \delta(\langle j - l\rangle_N)= {x_0(j)}?$$

Comment: $\delta (j-l) = 1$ when $j = l$. So, $$x_{0}(l) \delta(j-l) = x_{0}(j)$$ when $j = l$.

Comment: how about the $\frac{1}{n}$ and the sum?

Comment: You have a $1/n$ out the front of the sum, and an $n$ in the sum, so $\dots$